# What does it mean for a discontinuous piecewise function to have the same slope from the left and right at a point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I came across a piecewise function which isn't continuous but the slope at a certain point from the left and right are the same at $x=0$. What does this mean for the function, why wouldn't we consider this to be differentiable?

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
7x-6x^{3}-7 & \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
2x - \frac{20}{x+2}  & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}$$

I'm familiar with the theorem which states if a function is differentiable then it's continuous but this has puzzled me a bit.

Comment: The slope from the right is $7$, the slope from left does not exist (or, if you want, $f$ has the improper left derivative $+\infty$). I think you argue that $\lim _{x \to 0^-} f'(x) = 7 =  \lim _{x \to 0^+} f'(x) $, but that misses the point.

Comment: Helping to make sense to someone just learning calculus....  What I see as the big hang-up is that $f(0)$ doesn't change when you change the direction of approach.  So, in this example:  $f(0)=-7$ and when you use $\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ and $f(x)=2x-\frac{20}{x+2}$ there is no part of $f(x)$ that eliminates (or cancels) with the $f(0)=-7$.  The temptation is to declare that $f(0)=-7$ when finding the limit from the right (correct) and then use $f(0)=2(0)-\frac{20}{0+2}=-10$ when finding the limit from the left (incorrect).  $f(0)=-7$ no matter the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7x-6x%5E3%20-7%20if%20x%3E0%2C%202x-20%2F%28x%2B2%29%20if%20x%3C0) is a link to what the graph of OP's piecewise function looks like.

To determine whether or not $f'(c)$ exists, one can see if the following is true:

$$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = \lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}.$$

If either the LHS or RHS to the above equation does not exist, or the LHS and RHS exists but have different values, then $f'(c)$ does not exist.

For your piecewise function, let's determine whether or not the derivative of $f$ at $c = 0$ exists.

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{7x-6x^3 -7 - (-7)}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(7 - 18x^2\right) = 7.$

However,

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right) =  \lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(\frac{2x-\frac{20}{(x+2)} - (-7)}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(2 + \frac{7-\frac{6}{x}}{x+2}\right) \to +\infty,$

or rather it's more proper to say that the latter limit does not exist.

I also think it would be improper to say, " $-7 \neq +\infty$ hence $f'(0)$ does not exist."

Rather, it is proper to say that since the second limit does not exist, $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: This makes sense, but for the bottom workings for the limit which goes to +infinity, where did you get the (-7) from wouldn't it be (-10)?

Comment: No it would be $-7$ because $f(0) = -7.$

Answer (score 0):

Tge derivative is
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}$$
and there is no value of $f(0)$ where that limit exists